# issue installing python libraries in centos

Tags: python, centos, setuptools

Hoping this one will be an easy fix.

I am trying to install several python libraries to prepare my machine to have cuckoo sandbox installed. Whenever i try to run`python setup.py install`

(from just about every library i have tried to install so far) i get the error

```
  File "ez_setup.py", line 129
    except pkg_resources.VersionConflict as VC_err:
                                          ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I feel that i am missing something, but i just dont know what. If i was working in ubuntu i think this would be a lot easier for me.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Alternate syntax for catching exceptions: `except TypeError as exc`* was introduced in Python 3.0 and Python 2.6. (See [What's New in Python 2.6 - PEP 3110: Exception-Handling Changes](http://docs.python.org/2.6/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110-exception-handling-changes))

Maybe you're using lower version of Python and using setuptools 2.x.

According to [Setuptools pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools):

> **Python 2.4 and Python 2.5 support**
>
> Setuptools 2.0 and later requires **Python 2.6 or later**. To install
>   setuptools on Python 2.4 or Python 2.5, use the bootstrap script for
>   Setuptools 1.x:
>   https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap-py24/ez_setup.py.

Either upgrade your Python to a newer version (at least Python 2.6) or use setuptools 1.x.